# Is it possible to select the very first element within a container that's otherwise pure text without using classes or identifiers in pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is a purely hypothetical situation. When answering a question yesterday I came across a problem which I hadn't encountered before. The question itself was pretty flawed in that you simply wouldn't do what it was trying to achieve, but this problem may pop up in other situations. I wasn't able to give a working answer that didn't involve changing the markup, and I'd like to know if it's at all possible *without* changing the markup.

Take this example:

```
<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet...</p>
```

To style the first `strong` element you'd simply use `p > strong:first-child` or something similar. That's great and works well, but what if the first `strong` was optional and it was *only* the first `strong` that would require styling?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <strong>sit</strong> amet...</p>
```

Is it possible to ensure that only the very first `strong` tag here would be styled *without* using classes, identifiers or anything that could differentiate the two `strong` tags through the markup?

Here's a [JSFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/RNpsG/10).

**Note:** from the initial answers the question may have been a little misleading. The paragraph doesn't have to be the first on the page, so `p:first-child` isn't a solution. The first paragraph may not have this leading `strong` element - alternatively the second paragraph could also have this leading `strong` element.

**Edit:** I've updated the JSFiddle example to give a little more clarity of what should and shouldn't be styled.

Comment: Yes you can do this using jQuery

Comment: i think there is not way...because when `HTML` render how would browser or you will know that you missed first `strong` at LOREM..??

Comment: for this you can use strong:nth-child(1)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek i think OP asking about develop code where Browser will know that first strong need to be at `Lorem` not as `sit` and thats not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

The problem is that CSS selects only *element nodes*, and text nodes are not element nodes. So, as far as CSS is concerned, `<p>blah <b>blah</b> blah <b>blah</b> blah</p>` might as well be `<p><b></b><b></b></p>`.

In other words, your strong tag is the first *element* inside its parent regardless of whether there's text in front of it, even though it's not the first *node* when there's text in front.

Comment: @BoltClock, "element nodes?" I'd inquire further but I need to take my car vehicle to shop. ;)

Comment: That's right. Elements are nodes too, at least in terms of the DOM.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, couldn't think of a better way to word it. =/ (car vehicle... get it?) Just fooling around though, this looks just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this is what you are trying to do:

```
p:first-child > strong:first-child
```

Comment: No, in this the paragraph is assumed to be anywhere on the page. It's not necessarily the first paragraph, and the first paragraph may or may not have this leading `strong` element.

Comment: Yes, but the first `strong` tag would be entirely optional. Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/RNpsG/9/

Answer (score 1):

How about using * for any container, which has strong as its first element should be in different color:

```
* > strong:first-child { color:#f30; }
```

Or like this:

```
 * > p > strong:first-child { color:#f30; }
```

Comment: The `* >` is not necessary because `:first-child` implies there must be a parent.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - as pointed out in the comments, this solution falls apart pretty quickly. There isn't a CSS-only way to achieve this that I can see.

I've come up with a [pure CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Jzqha/). Here's the CSS (based on your amended example):

```
p > strong { color:blue; }
p > strong:first-child { color:red; }
p > strong:nth-last-child(-n+1) { color:blue; }
```

Which renders:

[image: nth-last-child example]

This makes use of the [:nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-last-child) selector, which is supported in all good browsers (and IE9+). That selector:

> …matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings after it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element

The order of those selectors is important because the specificity is the same for each, so we need to be over-riding the previous targeted `strong`'s with each subsequent selector.

Comment: Ah, this is almost a solution! Unfortunately it doesn't work when you have multiple `strong` elements which aren't at the beginning: http://jsfiddle.net/Jzqha/4/

Comment: No, it is a node problem, for the selectors `<p>...<strong>...<strong>...</p>` will always be considered as same as `<p><strong></strong></p>`

Comment: Exactly... CSS is unable to distinguish between `<a><b></a>` and `<a> foo <b></a>`, there's really no way around it. It's possible that some kind of `:first-line` positioning hack could sort of work, but it doesn't seem worth pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot more but I could not find any method that your need would be fulfilled, but anyway I have added a trick for your fiddle. **[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNpsG/14/)**
just add `<span></span>` inside to your first `<strong>` element and define your css... is **this Ok for you?**

**Edit**
Or you could define a blank strong inside your div `<strong></strong>` to make this first element.

Comment: That would involve modifying the markup. I'm after a pure CSS solution *without* modifying the markup.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
p strong:first-child { ... }
```

Comment: That's not what he's after. In fact, that code is given in the question. I believe he's trying to target the `strong` *only if* it is the very first element (i.e. in the exact position in the DOM that has been outlined).

Comment: perhaps I misread the question - he asked 'Is it possible to ensure that only the very first strong tag here would be styled without using classes'

Answer (score -1):

Look at this it might solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RNpsG/1/

```
body > p:first-child > strong:first-child { color:#f30; }
```

Comment: This only works if the first paragraph definitely has this leading `strong` element. I'll update my question.