# How to select a text node with CSS

Tags: html, css-selectors

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<h1> 
     <div class="sponsor"> 
          <span>Hello</span>  
     </div> 
     World 
</h1>
```

When I use the CSS selector `h1` I get `Hello World`.

I can't unfortunately change the markup and I have to use only CSS selectors because I work with the system that aggregates RSS feeds.

Is there any CSS selector which I can take only the text node? Specifically the `World` in this example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes-elements

Comment: Put it in a separate span...

Comment: you could apply changes to `h1` then undo them with `.sponsor`. It depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: use different span tag for the world and you can give it a id.

Comment: @Adrift : not() is possible in css

Comment: Why can't you change the markup again? It is invalid HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current state of CSS can't do this, check this link: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/)

The problem here is that the content you write to the screen doesn't show up in the DOM :P.

Also `::outside` doesn't seem to work yet (at least for me in Safari 6.0.3) or it simply doesn't generate the desired result yet.

Check my fiddle and then check the DOM source: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hCG4/4/)

Finally there are attribute selectors `a { content: attr(href);}`, making CSS able to read DOM-node attributes. There doesn't seem to be a `innerHTML` equivalent of this yet. It would be great tho if that was possible, whereas you might be able to manipulate the inner markup of a tag.

Comment: The document where `::outside` is defined has been abandoned pending a complete rewrite. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419614/enable-support-for-css3-outside-pseudoelement/10424878#10424878 Also, what this answer refers to as an attribute selector is not an attribute selector - that is something entirely different, this is simply a CSS function. Lastly, it doesn't make sense to have a CSS equivalent of `innerHTML` - `innerHTML` is an API for manipulating HTML, whereas CSS is just CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Bit of a workaround:

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
h1 * {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<h1> 
     <div class="sponsor"> 
          <span>Hello</span>  
     </div> 
     World 
</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost the opposite of a question I asked last week: [Is it possible to select the very first element within a container that's otherwise pure text without using classes or identifiers in pure CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472975/is-it-possible-to-select-the-very-first-element-within-a-container-thats-otherw)

The short answer is no. `"World"` in this example isn't an element of its own - therefore there isn't a way to select it.

What you would have to do here is style the `h1` then override that styling with `div.sponsor`. For instance, if you wanted "World" here to have a black background with white text you woud use something similar to:

```
h1 {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}

h1 div.sponsor {
    background:white;
    color:black;
}
```

Unfortunately, however, this wouldn't work if you were only wanting the word "World" styled and your markup had more than just that within `<div>Hello</div> World Foo`, for instance.

I don't believe it would be possible with pure CSS to style *just* "World" in this situation.

Comment: So it's not possible with pure CSS to select just the text `World`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I also met same problem, where I can't touch the markup and have no control with js. 
I needed to hide a text nodes in a div element, but the  element to remain visible. 
So here is my solution:

markup:

```
<div id="settings_signout_and_help">
        <a id="ctl00_btnHelpDocs" class="ico icoHelp" href="http://" Help Guide</a>
            Signed in as: <a id="ctl00_lUsr" href="Profile.aspx">some</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="Logout.aspx">Home</a>
                Sign out
        </div>
```

css:

```
#settings_signout_and_help {
font-size: 1px !important;
}

#settings_signout_and_help a {
font-size: 13px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps guys!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I had to remove the "World" text from html generated by a C# function.

I set the font-size to 0 on the 'h1' element and then applied my css to div class. Basically hiding the extra text, but keeping content in the div.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know how to do it with just CSS, but...

Using JQuery, you could select all the elements inside  except the stuff inside its child element

$("h1:not(h1 > div)").css()
and put whatever CSS effect you want inside there.