# CSS: How would I select a specific Text and hide it

Tags: html, css

I don't have access to html, but i want to test something... How would I select the text boomboomboom and hide it with CSS...

the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="bla">
  <div>
    <strong>some text</strong>
    <br />
    boomboomboom
  </div>
</div>
```

I tryed this:

```
.bla div {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
.bla div strong {
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

but this just hides "some text" instead of "boomboomboom"...

can anyone help me? http://jsfiddle.net/b26N7/1/

Comment: I dont think this is possible with css only.. you can use javascript to do it, css is based on elements, id, class not text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641889/select-text-node-with-css), it's the same thing. 
Conclusion is, you can't select the text node with the css at this moment(without wraping it in a html element), but you can do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `<br />` to separate the "boomboomboom" in next line.
 You can use `"display:block"` to show the "boomboomboom" in next line.

Then your css will work properly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uL9Rg/

Comment: He wanted to hide only the unwraped text node inside his div, not all the content