# How to exclude inner tag using CSS Selectors

Tags: html, css

I've the following example HTML and looking to extract the text only from the `a` tag excluding the inner `span` tag.

```
<a href="#" class="rate">
 <span>For Sale </span>
$450.00
</a>
```

Is there a way I can extract the $450 only using CSS Selectors. I tried to use `.rate` and `.rate:not(span)` but none of these working

**I'm looking for native CSS solutions only - Like using :not or some other. **

Comment: CSS only work on element not on text.

Comment: With pure CSS, it's currently impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by *"extract"* - so you mean "select" and if so, what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641889/select-text-node-with-css

Comment: if you need to retrieve the amount, you should use Javascript or jQuery, why do you need css anyway?

Comment: I'm using this application for data scraping : https://www.datascraping.co/doc/39/chrome-extension

Comment: Do you generate html output? and can you apply bit change on it?

Comment: CSS cannot detect text content...so you can't scrape it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to next sibling text of element.

```js
var text = document.querySelector(".rate > span").nextSibling.textContent.trim();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="rate">
 <span>For Sale </span>
$450.00
</a>
```

**Edit:**
If you want to use CSS, you can store price value in `data-*` attribute of `.rate` and use [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-elements in it. You can use attribute value of parent in [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) property of pseudo-elements using CSS [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

```css
.rate:after {
  content: attr(data-price);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="rate" data-price="$450.00">
  <span>For Sale </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can only hide the element so that its text gets hide.

for ex:

```
a.rate span {
           display : none;
      }
```

If you wan to achieve to get text only $450, You should go with Javascript or jquery.