# How to hide a text which has no tags, no id, no class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have that HTML :

```
<div id="google_translate_element">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr">
        <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
            <select class="goog-te-combo">
                <option value="">Sélectionner une langue</option>
                <option value="en">Anglais</option>
                <option value="es">Espagnol</option>
                <option value="it">Italien</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        Fourni par&nbsp;<span style="white-space:nowrap">
        <a class="goog-logo-link" href="https://translate.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png" width="37px" height="14px" style="padding-right: 3px">Traduction</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to hide the 'Fourni par ' : problem is: it does not tagged, does not haev a specific classs or id ?

Comment: What's the logic behind hiding that text? Because it's an (only) unwrapped `textNode` of its parent (`#google_translate_element`), because it follows the `#:0.targetLanguage` element, because it precedes a `<span>` with the `white-space:nowrap` style, because of the text itself, or because it ends with an `&nbsp;`? If we can understand the logic behind the requirement then we can (probably) offer a more general solution that's more widely applicable.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641889/select-text-node-with-css

Answer (score 4):

**jQuery solution :**

You could filter the text using `nodeType` and remove the text :

```
$('.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove();
```

```js
$('.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element">
  <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr">
    <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
      <select class="goog-te-combo">
        <option value="">Sélectionner une langue</option>
        <option value="en">Anglais</option>
        <option value="es">Espagnol</option>
        <option value="it">Italien</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    Fourni par&nbsp;<span style="white-space:nowrap">
    <a class="goog-logo-link" href="https://translate.google.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png" width="37px" height="14px" style="padding-right: 3px">Traduction</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS solution :**

You could use the `visibility` attribute to collapse the text and let the div and link `visible` :

```css
.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget {
    visibility:collapse;
}

.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget div,.skiptranslate.goog-te-gadget a{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element">
  <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr">
    <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
      <select class="goog-te-combo">
        <option value="">Sélectionner une langue</option>
        <option value="en">Anglais</option>
        <option value="es">Espagnol</option>
        <option value="it">Italien</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    Fourni par&nbsp;<span style="white-space:nowrap">
    <a class="goog-logo-link" href="https://translate.google.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png" width="37px" height="14px" style="padding-right: 3px">Traduction</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works, but since the HTML is generated by google, how to know when it is displayed ? Is there a CSS solution instead ?

Comment: I've added the CSS solution, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this only with css, you can also use font-size:

```css
.skiptranslate {
    font-size: 0;
}
.skiptranslate > span, .skiptranslate > div {
    font-size: 14px; /* Or whatever you want*/
}
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-gadget" dir="ltr">
        <div id=":0.targetLanguage">
            <select class="goog-te-combo">
                <option value="">Sélectionner une langue</option>
                <option value="en">Anglais</option>
                <option value="es">Espagnol</option>
                <option value="it">Italien</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        Fourni par&nbsp;<span style="white-space:nowrap">
        <a class="goog-logo-link" href="https://translate.google.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png" width="37px" height="14px" style="padding-right: 3px">Traduction</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```