# CSS style -- applying <p> tags with <br /> tags

Tags: html, css

So here's a sample I receive from CMS content:

```
<p>
    First Name
    <br />
    Location
</p>
```

Is it possible to add styling to specific content from before/after the `<br>` tags?

For instance, every text before the `<br>` tag I want `color: red` and anything afterwards I want `color: purple`

Comment: No, that's not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select text node with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641889/select-text-node-with-css)

Comment: this is possible with spans.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the text in a span with a class name and style it with CSS.  You can do this as much as you want to get the desired results.

The HTML

```
<p>
<span class="name">First Name</span>
<br>
<span class="location">Location</span>
</p>
```

The CSS Classes

```
.name{
color:red;
}
.location{
color:purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  .red {
    color: red;
  }

  .purple {
      color: purple;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
  First Name
  <br/>
  Location
</p>

<p>
  First Name Bis
<br/>
  Location Bis
</p>

</body>

<script>
var p = $( "p" ).has( "br" ); /* select all p tag with a br tag inside */
var regex = /<p>([\s\S]*?)<br>([\s\S]*?)<\/p>/g; /* regex, i'm not rly familiar but this one select the part between <p> and <br> (group 1) and <br> to </p> (group 2)*/
var i;
for(i = 0; i < p.length; i++){ /* foreach the selected elt */
  var newStr = "";
  while ((match = regex.exec("<p>" + p[i].innerHTML + "</p>")) !== null) { /* adding <div class = "red">(group 1 contents)</div> same with purple */
    newStr += "<div class = \"red\">" + match[1] + "</div><br>";
    newStr += "<div class = \"purple\">" + match[2] + "</div>";
    p[i].innerHTML = newStr;
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The below would accomplish what you're looking to do but it's not a great answer (very brittle).

```
<p><br></p>
p::before {
  content: "First Name";
  color: red;
}

p::after {
  content: "Location";
  color: purple;
}
```