# Select "Text" node using querySelector

Tags: selectors-api

I'm writing a parser that should extract **"Extract This Text"** from the following html:

```html
<div class="a">
    <h1>some random text</h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    Extract This Text
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

I've tried to use:

```
document.querySelector('div.a > :nth-child(3)');
```

And even by using [next sibling](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```
document.querySelector('div.a > :nth-child(2) + *');
```

But they both skips it and returns only the "p" element.

The only solution I see here is selecting the previous node and then using `nextSibling` to access it.

Can `querySelector` select text nodes at all?
**Text node:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Comment: My workaround is to use the `querySelector` to select the element and then extract the `#text` node with `Array.from(element.childNodes).find(node => node.nodeName === '#text')`

Comment: In this case, the Text node is the 3rd ChildNode, so you can access its text this way: `element.childNodes[2].textContent`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As already answered, CSS does not provide text node selectors and thus `document.querySelector` doesn't.

However, JavaScript does provide an *XPath*-parser by the method `document.evaluate` which features many more selectors, axises and operators, e.g. text nodes as well.

```js
let result = document.evaluate(
  '//div[@class="a"]/div[@class="clear"]/following-sibling::text()[1]',
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.STRING_TYPE
).stringValue;

console.log(result.trim());
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="a">
    <h1>some random text</h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    Extract This Text
    <p></p>
    But Not This Text
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

`//` means any number of ancestor nodes.
`/html/body/div[@class="a"]` would address the node absolutely.

It should be mentioned that CSS queries work much more performant than the very powerful *XPath* evaluation. Therefore, avoid the excessive usage of `document.evaluate` when `document.querySelectorAll` works as well. Reserve it for the cases where you really need to parse the DOM by complex expressions.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I should have been using from the start. Thanks! 
[MDN docs for Document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Comment: @icl7126 Thank you! I've added a performance notice. You should decide from case to case which method to use.

Comment: would this be more performant than recursing into an entire DOM structure to find all the Text nodes it contained?

Comment: @Michael I guess so, since it is a builtin. However, I never have done a performance test.

Answer (score 3):

**It can't**, though my answer isn't that authoritative. ( You may have figure it out)

You can check out this [select text node with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641889/select-text-node-with-css/15643202#15643202) or [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes/5688758#5688758).

Some **verbose** explaination(**maybe useless**, English is not my first language, sorry for some misusing of words or grammar.):

I was learning about [ParentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll) and since the `querySelectorAll()` method returning a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), I was wondering if it could select text node. I tried but failed; googled and found this post.

Argument in `querySelectorAll(selectors)` or `querySelector(selectors)` is a DOMString containing one or more [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (of course no containing  pseudo-element, otherwise the method would return null) **which only apply to elements (not plain text)**.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, no. But you can access it from its parent:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('div.a')

const textNodes = [...parent.childNodes] // has childNodes inside, including text ones
  .filter(child => child.nodeType === 3) // get only text nodes
  .filter(child => child.textContent.trim()) // eliminate empty text
  .map(textNode => textNode.textContent) // extract text content

console.log(textNodes[0])
// "Extract This Text"

// make it a function
const extractText = (DOMElement) => [...DOMElement.childNodes] // has childNodes inside, including text ones
  .filter(child => child.nodeType === 3) // get only text nodes
  .filter(child => child.textContent.trim()) // eliminate empty text
  .map(textNode => textNode.textContent) // extract text content

console.log(extractText(document.querySelector('div.a'))[0])
// "Extract This Text"
}
```